# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error with latitude-longitude addresses

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google maps API v3

I would like to plot about 500-600 pins on the map. I am getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error. Does it matter if I mannualy geocode the addreses in the database to lat/long? Is this a way to avoid the query limit of 2500 per day, since no address to lat/long translation will be made?

This is the code which I use

> Blockquote

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"       type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<style type="text/css"> #ppt-object-map { height:<?php echo $h; ?>px; width:<?php echo $w; ?>px; }</style>  
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
var myOptions = { zoom: <?php echo get_option("ppt_object_map_zoom"); ?>, center: new     google.maps.LatLng(44.69,-63.62), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("ppt-object-map"), myOptions);    setMarkers(map, featuredlistings);
}
var featuredlistings = [
<?php
if(!empty($postslist)){ $i=1;
foreach($postslist as $post){
$map = trim(strip_tags((get_post_meta($post->ID, 'map_location', true))));
if(strlen($map) > 5){
echo "['".addslashes(str_replace("-"," ",$post->post_title)).premiumpress_image($post-    >ID,"",array('alt' => $post->post_title, 'link' => true, 'width' => '120', 'height' =>    '100', 'style' => 'auto' ))."', '".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'map_location', true)."',   ".$i."],"; $i++; } } }
?>
];
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
var featuredlistings = locations[i];
DrawIcon(map,featuredlistings);
}
}
function DrawIcon(map,featuredlistings){
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('<?php echo PPT_FW_JS_URI; ?>/map/icon.png',
new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('<?php echo PPT_FW_JS_URI; ?>/map/shadow.png',
new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
var image = "<?php echo PPT_FW_JS_URI; ?>map/iconx.png";
var shadow = "<?php echo PPT_FW_JS_URI; ?>map/shadow.png";
var shape = {
coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
type: 'poly'
};
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': featuredlistings[1] }, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
shadow: shadow,
icon: image,
map: map,
position: results[0].geometry.location,
});
var boxText = document.createElement("div");
if(featuredlistings[0].length > 20){
var maph = -80;
var mapw = -160
boxText.style.cssText = "margin-top: 8px; background: #000000; padding: 5px; -moz-    border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;    padding-bottom:10px;";
} else{
var maph = -80;
var mapw = -70
boxText.style.cssText = "margin-top: 8px; background: #000000; padding: 5px; -moz-    border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;";
}
boxText.innerHTML = "<div class='map_container'>"+featuredlistings[0]+"</div>";
var myOptions = {
content: boxText
,disableAutoPan: false
,maxWidth: 0
,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(maph, mapw)
,zIndex: null
,boxStyle: {
opacity: 0.8
,width: "160px"
}
,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
,closeBoxURL: "<?php echo PPT_FW_JS_URI; ?>/map/close.png"
,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
,isHidden: false
,pane: "floatPane"
,enableEventPropagation: true
};
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(e) { ib.open(map, marker);     });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) { ib.open(map, this); });
var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
    } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +     status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can draw a pin for free using a lat/lon pair...

Comment: I mannualy geocoded the addreses to lat/lon pair, but I am still getting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error. Am I restrained to 10 QUERYS per second even with the lat/lon pair?

Comment: if you know the lat/lon of the visible map's corners, you can paint all 500 yourself at once over the map image. i used a google js lib that let you do the same thing: draw a pin without any web connection.

Comment: When you don't use the geocoding provided by google, what gives you the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT-error?

Comment: I am not sure. maybe the script is set to use regular address and not lat/lon coordinates ?? could be that the reason?

Comment: @user2533989You're not able to see it in map?

Comment: I can see the pins but after a bunch of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error windows which I have to close in order for the page to continue working.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @geocodezip  Here is the code ---> http://pastebin.com/7VbJnn0g

Comment: @Dr.Molle  Here is the code ---> http://pastebin.com/7VbJnn0g

Comment: @dandavis Here is the code ---> http://pastebin.com/7VbJnn0g

Comment: Links to code are discouraged.  Please post at least the relevant code (if all of it is too much) as part of your question.

Comment: @geocodezip I added the code which I use to the question part of that post

Answer (score 0):

It matters not if you manually geocode the addresses in the database.  It's the approach I've personally always taken when needing this information as you only want to geocode once, until they update their address.  It will be quicker and more efficient.