# ReferenceError: QUERY_LIMIT is not defined in Google Map Using Own Lats / Longs

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Thanks for any help you can provide! I've got a directions tool that lets users map a route to a start, finish, and 8 waypoints. I've also got a separate map webpage that loads about 2000 markers from a JSON object that uses latitudes and longitudes (no geocoding). I'm trying to combine these two into one mapping tool.

The problem is that when I run the combined map, I get an error in my console:

```
    ReferenceError: QUERY_LIMIT is not defined
    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER-QUERY_LIMIT){
```

I checked out [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error with latitude-longitude addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377082/over-query-limit-error-with-latitude-longitude-addresses) but it didn't seem to apply to my problem. Any ideas about what might be causing this error? Again, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the line of code it's complaining about, with whitespace added for clarity:

```
if( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER - QUERY_LIMIT ) {
```

Now you can probably see why that gets a `QUERY_LIMIT is not defined` message.

Can you find that code in your page? Should it have `_` where it has `-`, so it would read `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`?